# PHP Handle missing arguments and null values in functions

Tags: php, parameters, null

I want a function to signal error if no parameter is passed. Now it emits a warning but executes the code.

I look into this [PHP Error handling missing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100702/php-error-handling-missing-arguments) but I think is more of a question of "empty" casting the input as null or zero.

I'm using:

```
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Sep  6 2016 16:37:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I have:

```
function go($x){
    if(is_null($x))
        print("|nil|"."\n");
    else
        print($x."\n");
}
```

And getting the expected results as

```
go(33);
> 33
go("Hello world");
> "Hello World"
go(null);
> |nil|

$in = null;
go($in);
> |nil|
$in = 44;
go($in);
> 44
```

but if I invoke it without parameters I get

```
go();
> Warning: Missing argument 1 for go(), called in ...
> |nil|
```

In this example I'm printing |nil| but in the larger picture it should return the error (or null) to handle some place else.

I've looked into something like

```
function go($x){
    if(!isset($x)) die("muerto");

    if(is_null($x))
       print("|nil|"."\n");
    else
       print($x."\n");
}
```

But it kills (dies?:-)) both empty and null cases.

```
go();
> Warning: Missing argument 1 for go(), called in ...
> muerto

go(null);
> muerto
```

As usual this is an overly simplified example from a more elaborated code.

Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: I love it when they just *"GET and GO"*, don't you?

Comment: Yeah.... love it too ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use default value and `func_num_args()` function to handle a case when no argument passed. For example:

```php
function go($x = null){
    if(func_num_args() === 0)
        print("error: no argument passed"."\n");
    else if(is_null($x))
        print("|nil|"."\n");
    else
        print($x."\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before using a function you can do something like:

```
if (isset($x)) { // or can be !empty($x)
    go($x);
} else {
    echo "Error";
{
```

Or (even better) you can do something like this:

```
function go($x = null){
```

In this case a default value of `$x` is `null`, so if you will run a function without parameter it will become a `null`.

So it will be as follows:

```
function go($x = null){
    if(is_null($x))
        print("|nil|"."\n");
    else
        print($x."\n");
}
```

**About used functions**

[Default value of function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.isset.php)

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can set the param default value to null like so...

```
function go($x = null){
    if($x == null){
        //handle null value
    }else{
        //do something
    }
}
```